# Loop over NxN grid cells based of proximity to a certain cell

Tags: algorithm, loops, language-agnostic, nested-loops

I have a `N` by `N` grid. I have a certain grid cell labeled with `0`:

[image: checkered board]

I intend to loop over grid cells, starting with `0` cell, in this order:

- Start with cell labeled `0`
- Next cells are labeled `1`
- Next cells are labeled `2`
- ...
- Until the grid boundary is reached

How can I compose the loop?

---

I tried to follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10395074/3405291). But I cannot adapt it to suit my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill the entire grid using a [Breadth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search): Starting with the cell with value zero, it will expand in concentric waves, adding one to each subsequent layer further away from the center.

Here is an example in `Python3`

```
from collections import deque
from typing import List, Tuple


class Grid:
    """represents a grid of cells indexed like a matrix:
    rows first, then columns
    rows, cols, r, c, row, col, cr, cc are ints
    rowcol = tuple of ints
    """    
    eight_offsets = [(1, 1), (1, 0), (1, -1), (0, 1), (0, -1), (-1, 1), (-1, 0), (-1, -1)]

    def __init__(self, rows: int, cols: int):
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.cells = [[None for col in range(cols)] for row in range(rows)]

    def fill_grid_BFS(self, rowcol: Tuple[int, int]) -> None:
        """fills each cell with its distance from the cell at rowcol which is zero
        """
        row, col = rowcol
        self.cells[row][col] = 0
        queue = deque([rowcol])
        visited = set()
        while queue:
            current = queue.popleft()
            cr, cc = current
            rank = self.cells[cr][cc] + 1
            visited.add(current)
            for neigh in self.get_eight_neighbors(current):
                if neigh in visited:
                    continue
                r, c = neigh
                self.cells[r][c] = rank
                queue.append(neigh)
        print(self)

    def get_eight_neighbors(self, rowcol: Tuple[int, int]) -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:
        """returns the valid Moore's neighbors that have not been assigned a value yet
        """
        row, col = rowcol
        neighbors = []
        for dr, dc in Grid.eight_offsets:
            r, c = row + dr, col + dc
            try:
                if self.cells[r][c] is None:
                    neighbors.append((r, c))
            except IndexError:
                pass
        return neighbors

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        res = []
        for row in self.cells:
            res.append(' '.join(str(elt) for elt in row))
            res.append('\n')
        return ''.join(res)


g = Grid(8, 8)
g.fill_grid_BFS((5, 5))
```

#### output:

```
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 4 3 3 3 3 3 3
5 4 3 2 2 2 2 2
5 4 3 2 1 1 1 2
5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2
5 4 3 2 1 1 1 2
5 4 3 2 2 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The property all cells labeled one is that the maximum distance in both axes is equal one, the same goes on for every cell that is if the 0 cell is on the cell (x0, y0) label of cell (x, y) will be equal to max(|x - x0|, |y - y0|)

Thus, to iterate over all labels, we can use something like this:

```
for (l = 0 -> min(x0, y0, N - x0, N - y0) + 1:
  for (x = x0 - l -> x0 + l)
     #checking cell (x, y0 - l)
  for (y = y0 - l -> y0 + l)
     #checking cell (x0 + l, y)
  for (x = x0 + l - 1 -> x0 + l)
     #checking cell (x, y0 + l)
  for (y = y0 - l -> y0 + l)
     #checking cell (x0 - l, y)
  #checking cell (x0 - l, y0 + l)
```

you can merge loops iterating over x and y if you don't care that you iterate over adjacent cells.

ps: loop ranges are assumed to be closed on start and open in end. i.e. (x = a -> b) means range  (a, a+1, ..., b-1)